# Should I ever use the .html5 file extension?

Tags: html

Should I ever use the .html5 file extension instead of the .html extension? I just ran into this apparent file type today and was completely surprised that it even existed.

Is the .html5 file extension backwards compatible?

This is the only useful page that comes up quickly in a search: 
https://www.file-extensions.org/html5-file-extension

Comment: I think its not required to use .html5 extension. it does not make any difference. its the same .html file.

Comment: File extensions are completely dependent on how the web server is configured. You can give your pages the extension of `.foo` and as long as the server is configured to handle them properly it won't matter.

Comment: you can change extension to `.wtf` if you like, that makes no difference except it might not be recognized directly by your file explorer. That's the `Content-Type`header that makes the difference on the web.

Comment: It depends on your web server software. Common ones like nginx or apache will prolly identify it. But I would suggest to use 'html'.

Comment: Never seen it being used. My system (Win7) does not know what to do with a local test-file using it. A browser over the web won't care, it looks at content type, and then the content, never the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File extensions are just a small data structure. A file is named, and the name can contain dots in it. By convention, programs can split the name at the last dot, take what's to the right, and do something, including nothing.

For example, a file manager can display icons from its database of extension-to-icon relations, if the authors of that file manager took their time to code that.

An operating system can keep a database of extensions and open a file in a corresponding program afer, say, a double click.

Extensions can be ignored, used and abused. For example, you can pretty easily instruct your Windows to open all .exe files with Adobe Acrobat Reader. After that, you'll have to take another internet-enabled device and google how to fix the outcome. The fix will be just an instruction in the Windows registry.

Or, you can setup your webserver to process .html files with a PHP interpreter, which can seem mind-blowing at first glance.

**Should I ever use the .html5 file extension?**
You should not. But you may, if you want. You may use .html6 as well.

**Is the .html5 file extension backwards compatible?**
There is no such thing as file extension backwards compatibility. Think of widespread support instead — has it been embraced widely so that you can send it to your grandma via email, and her double click opens anything except «How would you like to open this file?» dialog? *(No, it hasn't)*

You can always rename your file using another extension in case of bad happenings.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not required to use .html5 extension. it does not make any difference. its the same .html file. – @Yunus Saha

File extensions are completely dependent on how the web server is configured. You can give your pages the extension of .foo and as long as the server is configured to handle them properly it won't matter. – @j08691